# If I change or remove the same URL from a site is it a bad impressions for Google or Google Webmaster

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-index

I am having an issue, before I make one page like this:

```
appna.php?ty=Skype Id is Coming Soon
```

But now I have to remove that page and link.  In the Webmaster Tool it's still showing that page with an error.  I'm confused on what I can I do?  If I change the domain is it a good impressions for Google?  And I'm changing web content like 2 or 3 times is it also good or bad  impressions for Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove a page from your website, it won't leave a bad impression on Google.

But, instead of removing the page entirely, consider putting a 301 redirect in.  This tells Google that the page you had was changed to something else.

Comment: Thank You For your Quick Response. This is sky id page now i don't to keep this if i redirect that error to client detail page is okay. and one more thing one client as 6 social network icon if i put redirect on all is okay or is come in to many redirect.

Comment: If you have social network links all pointing to the same page, I don't think there is a problem with that.